# Sublime text 2 build system

Tags: command-line, batch, sublime-text-2

I want to build a file using Sublime Text 2, and then do a simple copy. I managed to do the first thing using a build system, and I think it has to be possible to do the copy with the build system also (because I can do it in a batch file).

The batch script what does what I want to do is:

```
copy /b hang.bin+sectors.bin image.img
```

And the build system that I use is:

```
{
"cmd": ["copy", "/b", "hang.bin+sectors.bin", "image.img"],
"working_dir": "$file_path"
}
```

The error message that I get:

```
[Error 2] The system can't find the specified file
[cmd:  [u'copy', u'/b', u'hang.bin+sectors.bin', u'image.img']]
[dir:  C:\Documents and Settings\xxx\Desktop\Project]
[path: C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Ulead Systems\MPEG]
[Finished]
```

Yeah, I hardcoded the hang.bin file to see if that would work, but no. Normally I would use `${file_name}.bin` there.

I suspect the + syntax of the two files that are to be copied (to one new file) is the problem, but I'm not sure. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `where copy` in a command line and you'll see that `copy` isn't a program, but a built-in command provided by `cmd`. Sublime Text runs build systems natively, without `cmd`, so it doesn't recognize `copy`.

There's a workaround: execute the command through `cmd`. 
From `cmd`'s help (see [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd) or [this](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)):

```
CMD [/A | /U] [/Q] [/D] [/E:ON | /E:OFF] [/F:ON | /F:OFF] [/V:ON | /V:OFF]
    [[/S] [/C | /K] string]

/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
```

So, for example, `cmd /C notepad` will execute Notepad and exit immediately, without waiting for it to exit. `cmd /C copy` will work too, because it's executed through `cmd`. Your command should look like this:

```
cmd /C "copy /b hang.bin+sectors.bin image.img"
```

Remember about the quotes, otherwise `/b` and the rest of the command will be treated as arguments for `cmd`, not `copy`.

Comment: Thanks! What would the sublime-build-form of that be?
I tried a lot of things, but I can't get it to work...

Comment: What exactly have you tried? The last codeblock should be working, but remember about escaping quotes etc.

Comment: I tried converting that to JSON format by trying things like
`{
 "cmd": ["C:\\nasm\\nasm", "$file_name", "-f bin", "-o hang.bin"],
 "cmd": ["cmd /C \"copy /b hang.bin+sectors.bin image.img\""],
 "working_dir": "$file_path"
}` but that gives me the same error as before (error 2: the system can't find the file specified).
If I just copy the line, I get the message "Error trying to parse build system: Expected value in <path>/build.sublime-build:1:1"

Comment: 1. You can't have two fields with identical names in a JSON (I'm looking at `cmd`). If you want to issue more than one command, the simpliest way to achieve it is to create a batch file and start it from a build system. You can pass as many arguments as you wish and then issue your commands from that BAT file. 2. In build system paths you should use slashes, not backslashes - Sublime Text will take care of them and you'll avoid escaping problems. 3. I remeber that I once had to use double escaping, i.e. instead of `"` it should be `\\\"`. You can try that.

Comment: Clear! It worked out. My sublime build file: `{
 "cmd": ["<path>/assemble.bat", "$file_name"],
 "working_dir": "$file_path"
}`
My assemble.bat file: `C:\\nasm\\nasm %1 -f bin -o boot.bin
bfi -f=boot.img -l=bootflop ./floppy
bootcopy`
(As you can see, I don't use copy anymore, but a tool I wrote myself called bootcopy)

Comment: I tried `cmd /c copy file1 file2` (without quotes) simply from the command line,  and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

---

It works with paths and files with *`whitespaces`* by spilting up the arguments with `"arg" ,` such as:

`[..., "/C", "START", "${file_path}", "${file_name}"]`

---

Paste this into your **`Batch.sublime-build`** file.

```
{
    "file_patterns": ["*.bat"],
    "selector": "source.Batch",
    // This runs the batch file in cmds' console
    "cmd": ["cmd", "/C", "START", "${file_path}", "${file_name}"]
}
```

Your batch file can then be run in the CMDs' CLI. I suppose it's possible to pass arguments also but this may be a starting point for you.

The above will run cmd.exe and run the code in its native console. This will accept your inputs of the **.bat** file.

---

Here's a build that can be saved as **BatchStConsole.sublime-build**

```
{
    "file_patterns": ["*.bat"],
    "selector": "source.Batch",
    // This outputs to Sublime Texts' console
    "cmd": ["cmd", "/C", "${file}"]
}
```

The above will run the code in Sublime Texts' console. This will not accept your inputs of the **.bat** file. But still useful for debugging as it passes any arguments like the native CLI but just no interaction.

---

Relevant help:

`START` https://ss64.com/nt/start.html

http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems/configuration.html#platform-specific-options

https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/build_systems.html

Comment: (1) The OP seems to be trying to get away from having a batch file.  (2) Why do you throw a ``START`` command into this?

Comment: **(1)** He quotes: _Normally I would use ${file_name}.bin there._ so I assumed he wanted what I've shown **(2)** Because it'll only output to the ST console otherwise. I've shown two examples in the post. But I suppose: `"cmd": ["C:\\\\Windows\\System32\\cmd", "START /c $file"]` could be shortened to `"cmd": ["C:\\\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", "/c $file"]` but it doesn't affect the result. See this for help on `START` [link](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html).

Comment: (1) If you believe that people who read your answer might want to know more about the `START` command, you’re probably right, and it makes sense to include the link to the ss64.com page *in your answer.*  I’m already familiar with the command, so telling it to me isn’t as useful.  (2) You suppose `cmd` […, ``"START /c $file"``] could be shortened to `cmd` […, `"/c $file"`].  Therein lies the point of my question: why add an extra command word if it doesn’t affect the result?  (2½) I see that you’ve edited your answer to remove the `START /c`, which is an invalid command, … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  and changed ``"/c $file"`` to `"/C", "${file}"`.  (3) But doesn’t it affect the result?  I don’t use Sublime Text, and I’m not familiar with this “build system” stuff, but, when I use `START` from a Command Prompt window, it creates a new window.  (3½) I see now that you seem to acknowledge that difference.  I overlooked it because you used the word “console” rather than “window”.  (4) I see that you’ve removed the full path from your answer, but, for future reference, I doubt that you need quadruple backslashes after `C:`. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (5) I see that you’ve removed it from your answer, but I’m curious what you think a `&` means at the end of a CMD command.  (6) Thank you for bringing up file names and paths with whitespace;  I was going to mention it if you hadn’t.  Pursuant to that, you might want to explain why your answer says ``"START", "${file_path}", "${file_name}"`` (i.e., why file_path ***and*** file_name?).  ***Don’t explain it to me; I understand it.***  Put it into the answer.  (7) Why do you have `"${file_name}"` in one case and `"${file}"` in the other?

Comment: I don't see where you are going with all these comment/queries. Most of which you already know. If you decided to run `cmd […, "/c $file"]` for example in ST you'd find you're wrong and it throws an error if whitespaces are found. The link I've posted explains clearly to what those `${file_name}` and `${file}` are. If anyone actually wanting to use this answer wanted to know anything they can comment and I'll change the answer to the best of my ability....

Comment: (Cont’d) …This site would not even exist if all the so-called help files in the world were perfect, nor is my answer. I'll add the `START` link to the answer. I'm not going to start explaining why something doesn't work. What's the logic in that? _I don’t use Sublime Text, and I’m not familiar with this “build system” stuff, but, when I use"_ Why are you commenting if you're not familiar with it, tried using it and/or intend to use it?